# vue error 'Avoided redundant navigation to current location' when trying to reload page with new params

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue-router

I'm trying to reload page with new params on state changed:

```
@Watch('workspace')
onWorkspaceChanged(o: Workspace, n: Workspace){
  if(o.type === n.type && o.id === n.id) return;
  this.$router.push({name: this.$route.name as string, params: {id: `${n.id}`, type: `${ n.type == WorkspaceType.COMPANY ? COMPANY : PERSON }`}});
}
```

but receive error
`Uncaught (in promise) NavigationDuplicated: Avoided redundant navigation to current location: "previous location".`

I expect path to be changed from /profile/c/123, where 'c' is type param and 123 is id param, to /profile/p/321 and vice versa

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the problem. It's not in the router. I messed up function arguments. In watcher function first argument should be new value.
Thanks for trying to help